# JAVA ME Hello World

Tags: java-me, netbeans-7.1

I am using netbeans 7.1. When creating new ME project I don't understand Device profile. What is `ClamshellCldcPhone`, `DefaultCldcJtwiPhone`, `DefaultMsaPhone`, `DefaultFxPhone`?

After creating the project what will be the code for `hello world`?

Comment: If you are using Netbeans, how about using one of the tutorials on [their Mobility Trail](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/mobility.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netbeans already has the feature to create hello world and a sample application for you with no codding required

1. Launch Netbeans
2. Click New Projects
3. Select java ME -> Mobile Application
4. Click Next
5. Put Your Application Name and make sure **set as Main project & Create Hello MIDlet** is selected
6. Select Default emulator and click on finish
7. Click on Run to run your application

**My Advice**

They are lots of J2me Books for beginners online. I would advice you get one and learn the basics properly.